# PHPStorm sync how to ignore line separators?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, line-endings

If I run a sync with a server I get changes in all files because of different line separators. All files show no changes but a hint: "contents have differences only in line separators".

Can I make PHPStorm ignore those line separators?

Comment: About the close vote, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is"

Answer (score 22):

> Can I make PHPStorm ignore those line separators?

<del>There is no such option.</del>

<del>Thing is: there is no difference in the actual content (code) but it is still there in line endings (which is still part of the "content").</del>

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101502 -- star/vote/comment to get notified on progress -- **this ticket has been resolved since 2017.3 version.**

You have to use `Compare by: Text` [to ignore Line endings and charset](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101502#focus=Comments-27-4339171.0-0):

[image]

---

**Right now (Dec 2014)** I may only suggest to convert all of your local PHP/HTML/JS files to the same line endings (`Unix - LF`): PHP and browser on Windows have no issues using `LF` or `CRLF` as line ending.

- This option affects newly created files: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style --> Line Separator`
- For existing files you have to perform such conversion manually: select files/folders (or whole project) in Project View panel and use correct entry from `File | File Properties | Line Separators` (used to be `File | Line Separators` in the past).
  ~ It is also possible to change that from the status bar: for a currently opened file of course.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40472391/783119 -- see it with pictures.

Comment: I think you are right. I looked at `Settings | Tools | External Diff Tools`. That could be a solution with the right diff tool and parameters but I couldn't make it work yet.

Comment: I noticed that at least for _PHP Storm v2020.2.1_, the option for modifying existing files was moved to `File | File Properties | Line Separators`

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa Thanks, updated my answer with some up-to-date text.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to change your default line separator style to use the same as your server. To do that, open File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style and set the "Line Separator" option to the same option as on your server.

Another solution is to deactivate the "Inconsistent line separators" inspection in your inspections settings (File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Portability issues -> Inconsistent line separators).

Comment: I tried both options but it looks like they do only affect file editing but I would like to change the comparing behavior. I really don't care about line separators I would only like to see content changes.

Comment: on new versions (now as v.2016.2), the path to the option is in:
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> General -> Inconsistent line separators