# PhpStorm saving with Linux line ending on Windows

Tags: windows, phpstorm, line-endings

*Environment: Windows + PhpStorm*

**Issue**: PhpStorm saves file with Windows line endings - and for shell script it's issue so there is need to always convert after copying to server.

**Question**: Is possible to configure **PhpStorm** to save file with **Linux line endings** - `\n` and not `\n\r` (new line + carriage return)?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can safely use the `\n` line ending for `.php` and most of other files as well: PHP on Windows will read such files just fine.

---

**To set the default line ending** for all **new** files: go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style` and change `Line separator` option to the desired style (e.g. `Unix and macOS (\n)`).

[image]

---

**To change line ending for a particular existing file:** open the file and either change it via appropriate section in a Status Bar .. or via `File | File Properties | Line Separators`

[image]

[image]

---

**P.S.**

If you have **EditorConfig plugin** installed and enabled (*it's a standard plugin now / bundled for quite a few years*) then you can also configure this via [.editorconfig file](http://editorconfig.org/): this can be done on per file extension level so it's even more flexible than PhpStorm's own settings.

As a bonus: this will also work in another editor/IDE that supports`.editorconfig` files.

https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#end_of_line

Answer (score 0):

In JetBrains IDEAs 2022.3.2, they've moved the format around; so you can find it under 
`Settings > Code Style > General > Line separator`

[image]