# WebStorm - when commit by version control replace whole file instead of special changes

Tags: git, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I make some small changes in file, like on following screenshot:
[image]

and make commit with WebStorm version control, content of file is fully changed(instead of few changes).

My suggestions - issue with LF and CRLF, but I played a bit with that and didn't found how to solve this.

**P.S.** when I commit with `git add file_name` and `git commit` I don't have this problem.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhpStorm saving with Linux line ending on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470895/phpstorm-saving-with-linux-line-ending-on-windows)

Comment: @ikkentim I tried each line separator from setting, and every time whole file mark as changed, so your link doesn't help me

Answer (score 1):

I spend hours with this issue and finally, the following config solved my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When having the same issue and only wanting to suppress it for certain files after small changes I found it handy to use the Line Separator toggle on the bottom right in the status bar. Works like a charm.

[image: line separator toggle]